# Trouble with has_one Association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, has-one

I've been stumped by this problem for several hours now and I'm hoping someone can help me figure out why this code isn't working.

What I'm trying to do is create an account associated with a particular user. I can create a user, but when I go to create the account, it doesn't look like the form is posting to the create method in my controller (the array of form data shows up appended to accounts/new in my browser bar).

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email_address, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_one :account, dependent: :destroy

  before_save {|user| user.email_address = email_address.downcase}
```

And my Account model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cell_phone, :first_name, :home_phone, :last_name, :middle_initial, :work_phone
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :orders
  has_many :items

  #strip digits and return string of numbers
  before_save do |account|
    account.cell_phone = cell_phone.gsub(/\D/,'')
    account.home_phone = home_phone.gsub(/\D/,'')
    account.work_phone = work_phone.gsub(/\D/,'')
  end

  before_save do |account|
    account.first_name = first_name.capitalize
    account.last_name  = last_name.capitalize
    account.middle_initial = middle_initial.capitalize
  end
```

In my User Controller (this works properly):

```
def new
    if signed_in?
      @user = current_user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @user = User.new
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to new_account_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Sorry, something went wrong"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

And my Account Controller (where I feel like the problem is):

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  #before_filter :get_current_user
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def new
    @user = current_user
    @account = @user.build_account(params[:account])
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @account = @user.build_account(params[:account])
    if @account.save
      flash[:success]
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:error]
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

I have current_user and sign_in as methods in a Helper file.

And, lastly, my Account form

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |form| %>
    <%= render 'shared/user_form_error_messages', object: form.object %>

    <%= form.label :first_name, "First Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name %>

    <%= form.label :middle_initial, "Middle Initial (optional)" %>
    <%= form.text_field :middle_initial %>

    <%= form.label :last_name, "Last Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :last_name %>

    <%= form.label :home_phone, "Home Phone" %>
    <%= form.text_field :home_phone %>

    <%= form.label :cell_phone, "Cell Phone" %>
    <%= form.text_field :cell_phone %>

    <%= form.label :work_phone, "Work Phone" %>
    <%= form.text_field :work_phone %>

    <%= form.submit "Complete Account", class:"btn" %>

<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for your help. I've been googling examples, reading rdocs and have tried a bunch of different things. If someone could explain why my code doesn't work (as opposed to just giving me the answer), I'd be most grateful.

At @thesis request, here is the output from my log when I click "submit" on the form:

```
Started GET "/accounts/new?    utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=DQ5mOiICI0C83l9xgkSlvToQKyWjE3Adm3X3U0HJ1W4%3D&account%5Bfirst_name%5D=Jesse&account%5Bmiddle_initial%5D=A&account%5Blast_name%5D=Flores&account%5Bhome_phone%5D=555-555-5555&account%5Bcell_phone%5D=&account%5Bwork_phone%5D=&commit=Complete+Account" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-04 16:14:11 -0400
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Processing by AccountsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DQ5mOiICI0C83l9xgkSlvToQKyWjE3Adm3X3U0HJ1W4=", "account"=>{"first_name"=>"Jesse", "middle_initial"=>"A", "last_name"=>"Flores", "home_phone"=>"555-555-5555", "cell_phone"=>"", "work_phone"=>""}, "commit"=>"Complete Account"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'B_E1bsUASQhHC-Zb-6updg' LIMIT 1
  Account Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered shared/_user_form_error_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered forms/_form_account.html.erb (5.9ms)
  Rendered accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (13.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered forms/_form_header_signin.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 279ms (Views: 160.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)
```

Comment: Please update your question and add log part where you have form posting process.

Comment: @thesis is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood the problem first. However, it seems like you want to associate an existing `user` object with a new `account`. Here is a link that should help you.

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/11335976/1160106**

Big problem statement but clear and brief answer. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It didn't work, however. I got the following error: undefined method `user_accounts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd9b4046e98>:0x007fd9b4de5338> even though I modified my routes path following those instructions (i.e., using a singular resource nested under users).

Comment: Shouldn't be `user_account_path` instead of `user_accounts_path`? Notice the `accounts` to be `account`. What does the `rake routes` show?

Comment: Thanks Samiron, this helped a lot! I was also assuming that when a form was submitted, it would automatically post to my create method. So, I put the build_account and .save methods in my 'new' method and am just handling account creation from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helps you for building nested instances in your code.
In accountscontroller,

```
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @account = @user.accounts.build(params[:account])
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @account = @user.accounts.build(params[:account])
    if @account.save
      flash[:success]
```

Comment: Hi shanmuk, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Because it's a has_one relationship, there isn't an Active Record object for me to use the build or create methods on. According to the Rails docs, I have to use a build_association or create_association method to create the associated record.