# undefined method in form_for using polymorphic association in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

Let me explain what I'm trying to do, then ask my question. I'm a total newbie with Ruby/Rails, but an experienced developer.

**What I want**: I want to have developers, customers and admins. I want a common authentication mechanism.

**What seems to be best**: The way I think is best to model this is by having a User that deals with the authentication and then some kind of inheritance or something that extends the functionality for each of the user types.

**What I'm trying**: I'm trying a thing called polymorphic association (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) but I've missed something. At the moment if I go to `/developers/new`, I get the following

```
in developers/_fields.html.erb where line #4 raised:
undefined method `name' for #<Developer:0x00000002bafd18>
```

**user.rb** snippet

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_id, :profile_type
  has_secure_password
  belongs_to :profile, :polymorphic => true
  ...
end
```

**developer.rb** snippet

```
class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :skype_name
  has_one :user, :as => :profile, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

**routes.rb** snippet

```
resources :developers
```

**Developer#new** controller snippet

```
def new
  @developer = Developer.new
  @developer.user = User.new
end
```

**new.html.erb** snippet for Developers

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for (@developer) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

finally
**_fields.html.erb** snippet

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
...
```

The closest question I've found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335924/nested-routes-and-form-for-and-models-using-has-one-and-belongs-to) but I tried a few things from their answer but it didn't help.

I can create a new User and Developer that link to each other via the rails console but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong for the web.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What file is the error occurring in?

Comment: developers/_fields.html.erb I'll edit the question too. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This might not be it, but it looks like the form is assuming Developer has a name, but User is the one with a name.  Is there a way to put `<%= f.label [user in developer object] :name %>` ?  Or maybe the form should be for @user since that seems to be the more broad object?  I'm just now getting the hang of these ruby on rails forms, so I'm hesitant with my suggestions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the `user` attributes in the scope of the `developer` parent.  Use `fields_for` to modify the scope:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<%= f.fields_for :user do |u| %>
  <%= u.label :name %>
  <%= u.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

You'll also probably want to make the Developer model accept nested attributes for the User.  Have a look at some examples [in the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).

Comment: dang, should have had the confidence to post an answer!  Good to know I was on the right track though!  I'm saving this SO question for future reference.

Comment: Thanks! It's still broken, but because of auth checks now. The issue I had is resolved.